# Where is the css .fieldWrapper class defined? (referenced in the Django docs)

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, django-forms

I have some HTML code in a Django app written by someone else, and it uses a `.fieldWrapper` CSS class that isn't defined in the app.  I searched for `fieldwrapper` in Google, in the Django docs, and in the Bootstrap docs.  In the Django docs, I see it [being used in multiple examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/), but I don't see it documented anywhere.

Where is the `.fieldWrapper` class defined?  (and optionally, where is the documentation for it?)

I did a `pip3 install django` and searched the source code for `fieldWrapper` and didn't find any occurrences.

In my web search, I found `fieldWrapper` references in the source code for the python `django-form-tags` and `djangoformtags` packages.  I installed those packages and looked occurrences in the source code, and didn't see any definitions for `fieldWrapper` (but I could be wrong).

Comment: If you're not adding it in your own templates, a quick Google suggests it could be coming from https://django-formtags.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, do you have that library?

Comment: Nope, I don't have the django-formtags library.

Comment: I did a `pip3 install django-formtags django-form-tags` and looked in the source code at all `fieldwrapper` matches.  From what I can see, `fieldwrapper` is used but not defined.